# Do Pokémon kicked from gyms go away forever?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm very curious since I put down my best Pokémon and I have been told I will lose it forever when it is kicked out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't lose pokemon that are assigned to a gym, they will continue to defend the gym's prestige, for the particular team that currently owns the gym.

After your pokemon has been kicked out, it will need a Revive, as its HP will be set to 0 (you will also need potions to fully heal that pokemon).

Note that only pokemon with full health are allowed to be assigned to a gym.

Comment: Please stop saying 'pokemons'. Its extremely irritating.

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: As with "sheep," "fish," and "deer," the accepted plural of "Pokémon" is simply "Pokémon." The term originates in Japanese, which does not feature a plural inflection of the sort to which Anglophones are accustomed.

Comment: Thanks for the info, by the way I also don't know about fishes xD

Comment: Funny enough, in my original answer I said that HP wil set back to `Zero` instead of one, I'm wrong about that, but later in game update, it did became true, it's now 0, how predictable xD LOL.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't. Well, sorta...
You will assign it to a gym so it will defend it. While your Pokemon is defending, you can't do anything with it until it gets kicked out. If your Pokemon is pretty strong, it might be a while until you get it back.

You can still view its stats btw